Mi pagina web no aparece correctamente en las búsquedas de Google
Hace poco publiqué una pagina web y la di de alta en Google Search Console. Sin embargo me encontré con algunos problemas.

Al buscarla por su nombre, aparece la Url de la VPS, no del dominio, y como nombre dataweb.com.
Al buscarla usando site:, aparece en el dominio, pero pone como nombre Oracle.

En ambos casos tampoco aparece correctamente la descripción de la página.
La página esta subida a un Cloud Server con Nginx.
Use varios tags meta:

<meta name="og:title" content="[Pagina]" />
<meta name="title" content="[Pagina]" />
<meta name="og:description" content="[Descripción]" />
<meta name="description" content="[Descripción]" />

Y tambien:
<script type="application/ld+json"> 
{ 
"@context" : "https://schema.org", 
"@type" : "WebSite", 
"name" : "[Pagina]", 
"alternateName" : "[Otro nombre]", 
"url" : "[URL]"   
} 
</script>

